# Copy shortcut favorites from windows 7 windows explorer to a text file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that copy shortcut favorites from windows 7 windows explorer to a text file.

Here is a script that works:

```
$ShortcutsFile = 'H:\_ProfilBackup\Genveje.txt'

# Copy Shortcuts to file

if (!(Test-Path $ShortcutsFile)) { New-Item -Path $ShortcutsFile -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null }

$Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$HOME\Links" -Include *.lnk

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts){
$Properties = @{
    Shortcuttarget = $shortcut.Target
    Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath | Out-File $ShortcutsFile -Append
}#$Properties
New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
}#foreach
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
```

My question is:

I'm only able to get all the links path properties to a file when doing a:

```
Out-File from the PSObject -Property $Properties = @{ 

Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath | Out-File $ShortcutsFile -Append
```

Is there anyone who knows how to get all the links path properties to a variable?

$shortcut.Target only has the last file link

Is there anyone who knows another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what output you expect.
This script outputs the properties to screen (in list format)
and/or to a .csv file

```
$ShortcutsFile = 'H:\_ProfilBackup\Genveje.txt'

$ShortcutPath = "$HOME\Links" 
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

$ShortCuts = foreach ($Shortcut in (Get-ChildItem $ShortcutPath -Recurse -Include *.lnk)){
     $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut.FullName)
}

$shortcuts 
#$shortcuts | Export-Csv $ShortcutsFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample screen output:

```
FullName         : C:\Users\LotPings\Links\Desktop.lnk
Arguments        :
Description      :
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : ,0
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : C:\Users\LotPings\Desktop
WindowStyle      : 1
WorkingDirectory :

FullName         : C:\Users\LotPings\Links\Downloads.lnk
Arguments        :
Description      :
Hotkey           :
IconLocation     : ,0
RelativePath     :
TargetPath       : C:\Users\LotPings\Downloads
WindowStyle      : 1
WorkingDirectory :
```

sample csv:

```
"FullName","Arguments","Description","Hotkey","IconLocation","RelativePath","TargetPath","WindowStyle","WorkingDirectory"
"C:\Users\LotPings\Links\Desktop.lnk","","","",",0",,"C:\Users\LotPings\Desktop","1",""
"C:\Users\LotPings\Links\Downloads.lnk","","","",",0",,"C:\Users\LotPings\Downloads","1",""
```

Comment: Many thanks LotPings thinks it was just what I needed. Dont like the way the output is from my script. I'll try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

using this

https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-Shortcut.ps1

```
$shortcutinfo = Get-ChildItem -path "$HOME\Links" -Include '*.lnk' -Recurse | foreach-object -process {get-shortcut -path $_.fullname}

$shortcutinfo | export-csv -path H:\ProfilBackup\Genveje.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I'm not sure what you mean by get-shortcut?

Comment: He is suggesting that you use the function Get-Shortcut which is available at the link he included in the answer.

Comment: okay thanks for the info. I really want to find a way where I do not use a function. There must be a way to get all the links path properties to a variable from the above script

Comment: @Joe, I'm glad you found your solution, but without a reason, it seems that limiting your scripts by avoiding functions does not appear to be an advantage. if you click the link, you'll see that there is nothing malicious. a function in powershell is simply a tool in the toolbox like if statements, for loops, hashtables, and even variables. i hope you can eventually become more familiar with functions and how they can be helpful. take care.